# Javascript Function for mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse, sender

I am trying to change the following code so that instead of having to click-and-hold the linked image to make it bigger (150 into 300), I could click it once to make the image bigger, and click it again to make the image return to smaller. I have to do this with multiple images on the page. (Be forewarned, I do not really understand jquery and have a very basic understanding of javascript. But I'm learning!)

```
function Down(sender)
{ var thisWidth=parseInt(sender.style.width.replace('px',''));
    sender.style.width=(300) + 'px';}
function Up(sender)
{ var thisWidth=parseInt(sender.style.width.replace('px',''));
    sender.style.width=(150) + 'px';}'

<img src="picture.jpg" onmousedown="Down(this)" onmouseup="Up(this)" />
```

Comment: what if you  make 2 clicks on it simultaneously ?

Comment: @RishiPrakash How could you make two clicks simultaneously ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I mean one after another, with in a very short span of time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could toggle a class.

Firstly, you should set a class to target specific element(s) and setting `width` attribute is preferred method:

```
<img class="imgToggling" src="picture.jpg" width="150">
```

Now, set relevant CSS for a `big` class:

```
.big {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Then on click, toggle this class, binding event using jQuery (preferred over inline scripting):

```
$(function () { //shorthand for document ready handler
    $('.imgToggling').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('big');
    });
});
```

### -DEMO-

If you wish to get some kind of transition, add this CSS rule e.g:

```
img.imgToggling {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

### -DEMO with transition-

Comment: i liked the transition one.

Comment: ok, that transition in the demo is PRETTY! my question is with the width property, can i add that with css for all the images, or is there a reason that would cause issues?

Comment: also, i do not know how to bind an event using jQuery, if you could explain that, it would help a lot.

Comment: That's already in this answer. If you are using dynamic elements (imgs), you need to delegate it. The web is full of already good tutos

Comment: @deganu Didn't so your previous comment. Just set common class to all images and then use as CSS rule: `img.imgToggling { width: 150px; }`

Comment: ok, i have it working, and it is really pretty, thank you for your help. One further question, is there a way to make it so that only one image can be big at a time? if you click one image without reclicking it and then click another image to make it big, then you have two bigs in a row, messing up the layout.

Comment: @deganu Something like that e.g: `$('.imgToggling').not(this).removeClass('big');`  http://jsfiddle.net/4p48gphm/2/

Answer (score 1):

*I have to do this with multiple images on the page.*

Then you can do this with jQuery *(as jQuery is tagged)*:

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
     var thisWidth=$(this).width(),
         setWidth = thisWidth >= 300 ? 150 : 300;
     $(this).width(setWidth); 
});
```

<sub>assumed if images are not dynamically generated or placed with ajax in the dom.</sub>